# There are no applicable items for return in this order

Tags: product, orders, products-management

I am going through the RMA process, I have placed 4 orders now with different products, and each time I try to create an RMA, I get the following error message

```
There are no applicable items for return in this order
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You are talking about the enterprise edition? Or a module? Did ou ship your items?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception is thrown in `Enterprise_Rma_Adminhtml_RmaController::newAction()` if this piece of code returns false.

```
Mage::helper('enterprise_rma')->canCreateRma($orderId, true)
```

Digging further in `Enterprise_Rma_Helper_Data::canCreateRma()` this returns false if
`$this->getOrderItems($order)` returns no items or if (`$forceCreate || $this->isEnabled())` returns false.
The second case can be excluded because $forceCreate is true (is the second parameter sent to the method `canCreateRma()`).

This means that `$this->getOrderItems($order)` returns no items.
This is equivalent to

```
Mage::getResourceModel('enterprise_rma/item')->getOrderItems($orderId)
```

returning no items.

This can mean that `Enterprise_Rma_Model_Resource_Item::getOrderItemsCollection()` returns no items. this happens when there are no items in the order with 'qty_shipped > qty_returned'.

If this is not the case and `Enterprise_Rma_Model_Resource_Item::getOrderItems()` still returns no items maybe your products are not marked as returnable.
See this piece of code in the same method:

```
if (!Mage::helper('enterprise_rma')->canReturnProduct($product, $item->getStoreId())) {
    $allowed = false;
}
```

Check the value of the 'Enable RMA' attribute for your products. If it's 'No' set it to 'Yes' or 'Use config'.

If it's set to **'Use config'** then check the value of this field in **System->Configuration->Sales->RMA Settings->Enable RMA on Product Level**. This should be 'Yes' (if you want all the products available for RMA).

Let me know if this helps in a way. I hope I was clear in the explanations.

Comment: I Have debug same code in magento2. But when product is out of stock i cant able to return it. but if product is instock it works. Have any idea?